# how to add an extension to a filename in shell script

Tags: shell

Basically, because I had to benzip2 the .bz2 files, I ended up without any extension, but these files should be '.hdf4' files.

So, I can do that one by one, but I d like to go through all the files I have in my directory.

So for one single file:

```
     mv A2003119.L3m_DAY_PAR_par_4km A2003119.L3m_DAY_PAR_par_4km.hdf4
```

trying now to go through all the files;

```
     mv *4km *4km.hdf4
```

which doesn't work...

so I tried something else:

```
for i in *4km;
    do mv $i(*4km) $i(*4km.hdf4)
done
```

I have no idea how to write that correctly.... please any help very welcome!
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your filename is in `$i`, it's there in full -- you don't need to do anything else that references the `4km` portion within the loop.

```
for i in *4km; do
    mv -- "$i" "$i.hdf4"
done
```

See [BashFAQ #30](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030) for more comprehensive documentation on performing renames -- operating recursively, stripping old extensions, etc.

Comment: Yes! that s what I was looking for! I must say I m new to Bash and shell script. Thanks so much!

Comment: OK - I got it now the '$i', however why putting '--' ??

Comment: @sophie, '--' generally means end of options - anything after that should not be treated as an option. So this will prevent something called '-filename' from being interpreted as an option by mv and instead as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Most distros will come with the `rename` command (sometimes `prename`) which will do the heavy lifting for you:

```
rename -n -v 's/$/\.hdf4/' *4km
```

That command won't actually *do* anything, it will just show you *what* would be done.

Once you're satisfied, you can run it again but without the `-n`, that will actually rename them.

The `rename` command uses a Perl command to convert the source to target file name. In this case, it's a substitute command `s` which replaces the "end of entity" marker `$` with the text `.hdf4`, effectively appending that extension to each file name.

Comment: I think I m unsure about what does mean the s/ then /\